# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Temp (Access Denied)

Tags: java, telegram-bot, inputstream, fileoutputstream, access-denied

What a problem may be? Full code for telegram bot for user upload file to the local disk.

private File downloadFileFromTelegram(String fileName, @NonNull String fileId) throws TelegramApiException {
GetFile getFile = new GetFile();

```
    getFile.setFileId(fileId);
    org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.File file = execute(getFile);

    // Use the system's temporary directory
    Path tempDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    Path filePath = tempDir.resolve(fileName);

    // Use try-with-resources for the URLConnection and InputStream
    try (InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(file.getFileUrl(getBotToken())).openStream());
         FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath.toFile())) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return filePath.toFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle the exception as needed
        return null;
    }

}
```

Is it another methods for this?

Comment: Which line is causing the exception? The `InputStream` or the `OutputStream`? I get the feeling that the user running the process does not have permission to write (or maybe read) from the directory.

Comment: does your system have a `C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Temp` directory? And if it is a directory, you sure cannot (over)write it... seems like `fileName` is empty (but we cannot see its value)

Comment: Add the full exception stacktrace to the question. Where is the file name defined.

Comment: File and directory exist  (this is a file and dir on my comp)

Comment: `Temp` is a file?? Usually it is a directory, and apparently posted code is trying to write directly to it as a file, instead of to a file inside that directory (I am assuming, based on title of this question, that `fileName` is empty - as I already wrote)

Comment: Yes, this is a temp dir. How can i create filename? Path tempDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"+ fileName));
        Path filePath = tempDir.resolve(fileName);  ?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\S\User (Access Denied)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:289)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:230)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
 at org.example.NewOneMusicBot.downloadFileFromTelegram(NewOneMusicBot.java:116)
 at org.example.NewOneMusicBot.extractMusicReferences(NewOneMusicBot.java:137)